# Clear Sorting from DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, dataview

I have a `dataview`. Source of `dataview` is a `view` from `sql server`.
`Dataview` is sorted. Like this:

```
dv_building.Sort = "bld_number"
```

this `dataview` is a `datasource` to my `datagird1`:

```
DataGrid1.DataSource = dv_building
```

Now I want to remove sorting `dv_building.Sort = String.Empty` but the view of my data grid was changed, because sorting was removed, ie `dataview` was returned to their default sorting, probably by clustered index.

How can I remove sorting, but the actual sorting remain by `bld_number`? Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to keep your default sort why can't you sort on SQL server site and load already presorted data into `DataTable`?

Comment: Hi Dkozl, Thank you for your update.  our exact requirement is disable the sorting while editing the custom control(bounded to DataView) . Please help on this how to achieve this

Comment: it will be refereed Grid too , use something like clone . Reference must you needed ?

Comment: dHi  Smith ,thank you for your response ,Yes we have created customgrid like DataGrid with sorting,filtering ,Grouping function. We want to provide the Sortingoption for Disablesortingonedit on that. We need to disable the sorting in  DataView while editing the customgrid control. It is possible to maintain the current view in Datatable while clearing the sorting

Comment: It is possible to disable the sorting in particular DataRowView present in the DataView?

Comment: @Raja, can you clarify your question?  If you want the sorting to remain, why do you want to remove the sorting?

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround to achieve requested behaviour: implementation of class derived from Datatable is accessible for me, additional column appended to Columns:

```
Columns.AddRange(
                new DataColumn[N]
                    {
                        ...
                        new DataColumn("Order",       typeof (int))
                    }
```

I enumerate this column with order numbers after each data view column modification (column participated in sort). When I need freeze sorting I switch DataView.Sort property to this "Order" column. To unfreeze - dataView.Sort = regularSortCriterion.